# I am getting two errors, Can anyone help me find them?

Tags: javascript

I am getting two errors:

> TypeError: window.geoTest is not a function
>
> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

What do these errors mean? I can't see where I am missing a semicolon. What does window.geoTest is not a function mean?

```js
"use strict";

var waitForUser;

function geoTest() {
 waitForUser = setTimeout(fail, 10000);
 if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(createMap, fail, {timeout: 10000});
 } else {
  fail();
 }
}

function createMap(position) {
 clearTimeout(waitForUser);
 var Lat = position.coords.latitude;
 var Lng = position.coords.longitude;
 var mapOptions {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng), 
  zoom: 10
 };
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}

function fail() {
 document.getElementById("map").innerHTML = "Unable to access your current location";
}
```

```html
<body>
   <header>
      <h1>
         Hands-on Project 10-3
      </h1>
   </header>

   <article>
      <div id="cities">
         <div id="beijing">Beijing</div>
         <div id="paris">Paris</div>
         <div id="rio">Rio de Janeiro</div>
      </div>
      <div id="caption">
         Your location
      </div>
      <div id="map"></div>
   </article>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&callback=geoTest"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: var mapOptions { //an error is there.. = missing

Comment: It seems as though `script.js` needs to be loaded before `google maps` because you are using `geoTest` as a callback and that function hasn't been created yet. Try swapping the `script` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

This error is due to the code segment below:

```
var mapOptions {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng), 
    zoom: 10
};
```

Because you are missing a the assignment operator, `=`.

```
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng), 
    zoom: 10
};
```

That should have been a pretty simple error to notice even though the error said you were missing a `;` because the error normally provides a line number where the error occurred. Another thing is that usually that is thrown for any syntax error and usually pretty close to where the syntax error is. So, what I usually do when I see an error like that I look for any syntax error whatsoever.

---

> TypeError: window.geoTest is not a function

I would like to state that I do not know if you are using `google maps` api correctly, but I believe this error is because you are using a function that hasn't been created yet (In other words, a variable not defined as a function or an undefined variable being used as a function). So, here you need to go to the place where you use the function and that is here:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&callback=geoTest"></script>
```

Which comes before you load `script.js` which defines your function. To fix this swap the places of the `script` tags to get:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&callback=geoTest"></script>
```

Now, the function will be defined for the callback.

---

Answer (score 1):

Please correct this, you missed "="

```
var mapOptions {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng), 
    zoom: 10
};
```

To

```
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng), 
    zoom: 10
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `geoTest()` called in https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js, you have to have code in https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js that will call it. It won't get called just because you put it in the URL. You would need to code parse it out of the URL and then call it.

Or, alternatively, you can hook up a notification when the script has finished loading and just call `geoTest()` yourself from outside of https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js after https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js is fully loaded.

To detect when the external script file has loaded successfully and just call `geoTest()` yourself.

For Reference Click [here](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/109)!